# Debugging I2C, Effect of Oscilloscope Probes

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c

Working on a simple I2C setup: Raspberry Pi connected to a WM8731 audio chip.  The Raspberry Pi configures the WM8731 (which is write only) over I2C.

Problem is WM8731 doesn't always respond with ACK.  I have logic analyzer attached to the I2C lines, and about 5% of the time the transmissions end in NAK.  No other devices are on the bus.

The curious thing is when I attach oscilloscope probes to the lines, it greatly increases the number of NAKs.  The scope shows nice sharp transitions on SDA and SCL, but sometimes the WM8731 just doesn't pull low for ACK.

What could be going on such that merely attaching the scope probes would make the problem worse?

Signals during proper transmission:

[image]

Signals during NAK:

[image]

Comment: Looking at the WM8731 datasheet ( https://statics.cirrus.com/pubs/proDatasheet/WM8731_v4.9.pdf ), it does not appear to have an I2C interface.  It says that it has an I2S interface.

Comment: In fact it does although it's labelled MPU interface (maybe because of licensing?). You can even selected either SPI or this MPU interface. Yet, this is the configuration interface. The actual data interface is I2S

Comment: What values for Pull-Ups do you have on your I2C bus? What are your logic levels on the WM8731 and the Arduino? Do you see any mid-level voltages on your bus at any time during communication (such as 2 drivers driving the line simultaneously)

Comment: Right, I2S is used for the audio data, but it has a 2 wire MPU control interface which is connected to I2C

Comment: WM8731 and RPI are at 3.3V.  I2C pulled to 3.3V.  Oddly, the situation seems to improve with lower value pull ups.  Started with 4k7, and get few NAKs when they are swapped with 1k.

Comment: How long is cable and where else is it earth-grounded?

Comment: WM8731L is std CMOS threshold, I2S is 74HCT or TTL threshold logic, I2C is std CMOS threshold. http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva689/slva689.pdf

Comment: which cable?  I2C wires are about 5cm from one board to the other.  Scope probe cable is regular 1m or so.  all connected to same electrical outlet

Comment: Your RPI seems to have difficulty pulling SCL, SDA low, whereas the WM8731L has no problem. Could be a ground-connection problem, or there could be ground-currents causing a ground offset between these two chips.

Comment: What is your BUS bit rate? Have you tried to slow it down? Anyway this being so sensitive to little and unnoticeable rising time tweaking makes me think data is sampled on the wrong clock edge, i.e. while changing and not in the middle of stable period. I'd rather have a thorough look to protocol timechart, both ends, on MPU and WM.

Comment: Second @carloc suggestion. Check the timings of your I2C configuration, especially _minimal delay between data packets_. The fact that datasheet says "SPI compatible" but does not say the same about I2C could be licensing, but also could be bad compatibility. Reducing bit rate is best bet, and an alternative to reducing pull-up values

Comment: Also, "Oddly, the situation seems to improve with lower value pull ups." what is odd about it? stronger pull-ups means better slew rate, which is especially important at higher speeds. So, it is not odd, it is actually expected

Comment: Only odd that the 4k7 pull-ups should make it so much worse.  Bus speed is only 100kHz, and there are still relatively sharp transitions even with the 4k7.  So yes, going to have a closer look at timing as @carloc suggested.  Thanks everyone for your input!

Comment: The lower R pullups means less ingress voltage from noise current impulses. V=IR Slew rate here is fine, is this the worst case at Rx?

Comment: Removing the scope probe on SCL (while keeping the one attached to SDA) improves the situation.  Adding extra capacitance to SDA (100pF) and the NAKs disappear completely.  Slowing bus speed also helps... so seems like some timing incompatibility.

Comment: Use probes on x10 to minimize effects.

Comment: I'm more and more convinced you are sampling on the wrong edge... There is no shortcut, you should debug protocol timing down to the bits.... BTW changing pull-ups and so may get it working, but if dont spot the problem first you only have something critical and not reliable

Comment: looks like signal quality issue. What are the pull-up resisters on board on I2C Lines. DId you changed them and saw the response.

Comment: Two things. Check the drive strength setting on the R.pi pins. It may be set to the weakest drive. Also check the pull-up - should be in the 2k or less range.

Answer (score 2):

### new

I would be curious to know if a 1MHz snubber at the Rx would reduce NAK error rate.

C=560pF in series with 220 Ohms across Rx to 0V. Some adjust may be necessary.  e.g. 500 Ohm 270 pF

---

### old info

I2S uses 74HCTxx or TTL logic thresholds.  I2C uses std CMOS thresholds.

If the Vcc of each endpoint is floating, connecting a scope probe with an inductive long ground lead adds a common mode voltage (0V) than may differ from the "floating" ground and due to CM noise coupling at each end , some differential voltage can result.

It is hard to assess your CM noise without measurements between each ground with a current shunt.

The cable will have 100pF/m or so of capacitance and adding 10nH/cm of scope ground clip can induce a resonant impedance that may cause ringing.

So investigate noise ingress and experiment with earth grounding at either or both ends of the communication.  Also, consider twin probes in A-B for signal integrity such that when both probes are on the same signal it produces a flat line. ( Vdif=0)

Depending on cable lengths and bit rate, a CM ferrite transformer can help raise the CM impedance to radiated noise.

**The R pull-up depends on cable capacitance and bit period vs risetime and amount of noise ingress.**

### http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva689/slva689.pdf

---

Comment: I tried a 470pF in series with 220 Ohms across SDA to GND, and another one on SCL.  This eliminated the NAK completely!  Separately I tried adding 220 Ohm series resistors to SDA and SCL near the slave.  This also eliminated the NAKs.  But still trying to understand why either of these remedies would be necessary for this simple setup  (single master, single slave, separated by a few inches, without and noise or spikes that I have been able to observe).

Comment: Think of ringing impedance mismatch for cables>1m and EMI as a current source across lower R for lower noise. It’s all about SNR and signal integrity.  twisted pair is bout 220~240 Ohm differential impedance on most. The probes can couple noise thru capacitance currents from ground differential , If desired you can test with an AC electric drill near cable for error rate margin improvement from experiments with snubber load.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a fast interface (400 kHz max) so if it is sensitive to small amounts of additional capacitance, then you aren't meeting the timing specification in the datasheet, for example the setup and hold times in figure 8.

It is difficult to check this using the traces you have given, but maybe the clock is the wrong polarity with respect to the data transitions, and needs to be inverted.

Comment: Does the I2C clock look like it's inverted, or why do you say maybe?

Comment: I say 'maybe' because it isn't clear from the scope traces ; if they had a faster timebase, we could check the timing against the data sheet, and be sure.